# How can I hide the camera gizmo in Unity?

Tags: unity, camera

How can I hide the camera gizmo in Unity?

As said [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/visually-hide-main-camera-icon-in-editor.524777/) I tried to use the gismos menu in the top of my Scene view. But it does not work. Why?

Also, I tried saving my scene and project after the gizmo changes. Did not help. I have the **Unity 2020.1.17f1**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll note there are two columns in the Gizmos menu:

- one for the **gizmos** (like the white wireframe box that shows your camera frustum),
- and one for the **icons** (like the picture of a camera or light that shows the location of those objects, even when not selected)

**Click the camera icon** *next to* the checkbox in the Gizmos menu to hide the camera icon in your scene.

[image]